# Allow only Numbers and Hyphen declaring a negative number in a textbox

Tags: c#, regex, winforms

I tried to get textboxes to only allow numbers and a hyphen declaring a negative number however i researched and tried to replicate what i found and it doesn't work. maybe im missing something but i have no clue about Regex so maybe its wrong. but it doesn't update and accepts letters and other characters

```
Regex reg = new Regex(@"^[0-9-]*$");
bool textChangedByKey;
string lastText;
private void Team1Q1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    TextBox senderTB = sender as TextBox;
    if (char.IsControl(e.KeyChar)) return;
    if (!reg.IsMatch(senderTB.Text.Insert(senderTB.SelectionStart, e.KeyChar.ToString()) + "1"))
    {
        e.Handled = true;
        return;
    }
    textChangedByKey = true;
}

private void Team1Q1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    OnTeamInfoChanged();
    TextBox senderTB = sender as TextBox;
    if (!textChangedByKey)
    {
        if (!reg.IsMatch(senderTB.Text))
        {
        return;
        }                
    }
    else 
    {
       textChangedByKey = false;
       lastText = senderTB.Text;
    }

}
```

Comment: It works for me. I had to comment out `OnTeamInfoChanged();` since I have no idea what that is. Hyphens and numbers show up when typed, but letters and other punctuation do not. What isn't working for you?

Comment: You may want to change your pattern to `^-?[0-9]*$` so it only allows a single hyphen, and only at the start of the input. And keep in mind that this doesn't support decimals; only integers.

Comment: as i said its not preventing anything from being input

Comment: You might have to provide more code from your actual project. The code you posted above, with the exception of the aforementioned `OnTeamInfoChanged();` line, works exactly as your described intentions.

Comment: oh i think i figured it out. I don't have it declared properly in the designer. i have this but it comes back and error now for some reason thats probably simple `this.Team1Q1.KeyPress += new System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs(this.Team1Q1_KeyPress);`

Comment: Here's what Visual Studio generated in my designer class: `this.Team1Q1.KeyPress += new System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventHandler(this.Team1Q1_KeyPress);`

Comment: wow.. 1 thing... and that concludes this problem. and another problem arises but at least this one is fixed thank you, why don't you put the regex code for the hyphen at the beginning and ill choose it as the answer lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing the Regex pattern to `^-?[0-9]*$` would only allow a single hyphen, and only at the start of the input.

Wiring up the KeyPress event handler in the designer class like so should cause disallowed characters to get filtered out:

```
this.Team1Q1.KeyPress += new System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventHandler(this.Team1Q1_KeyPress);`
```